# dart Event .returnValue = X

Tags: dart, deprecated

I have old code, and I'm not sure how to change it, I need to use the old .returnValue, but it isn't there anymore, how can I fix this?

```
  rootElement.onSelectStart.listen((Event e) {
    e.returnValue = false;
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this indicates if the event was cancelled.

I think defaultPrevented is what you are looking for.
http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/Event.html#preventDefault
http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/Event.html#defaultPrevented